# Formio - How to add Javascript from the Builder? (runs 2 times or more)

Tags: formio, angular-formio

I am using the **Formio **Plugin.
What is the correct way to add "Javascript" to the Builder?

I tried this and other ways:

- I created a "Text Field" component.

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Et2Bl.jpg)

- I placed a "Console.log" in "Custom Default".

[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzyhQ.jpg)

[image3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sewmY.jpg)

- Finally, when I save my form, I open it and my console shows my console.log 2 times :(

[image4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gH08W.jpg)

Why did this happened? I've tried reading the documentation, but I'm having a bit of a hard time understanding it.
I hope someone can see this. I thank you very much!!